# Increment version number and data

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a file that reads something like this.

```
// calcmarks, version 1, released Fri May 8
```

I am trying to make a new shell script that increments the version number and date of the original file. I have been trying to use awk and sed, but have had no luck.

```
// calcmarks, version 2, released Fri May 8
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually need to programatically increment the values, or just to write new values supplied on the command line (perhaps including the current datetime)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perhaps not the most robust approach, but you could do something like this:

```
awk -F, -v date="$(date)" '
  $1 == "// calcmarks" {
    vers = substr($2,10); 
    printf "// calcmarks, version %d, released %s\n", vers+1, date; 
    next
  } 
  1
' file
```

With GNU awk (`gawk`) you can modify the file inplace by adding `-i inplace` to the command line options. Otherwise you will need to redirect to a temporary file, and then rename.